# Derivative calculation for AdaBoost

Tags: derivatives, machine-learning

My math are a little bit rusty, I'm trying to reproduce the derivative of the below equation w.r.t α from this [paper](https://sci2s.ugr.es/keel/pdf/algorithm/articulo/2007%20-%20PR%20-%20Sun%20-%20Cost-Sensitive%20boosting.pdf) (equation 4.9, result on 4.10).

[image]

The authors estimate α by zeroing the first derivative of the right-hand side of inequality. It would be really helpful to see the intermediate steps.

Answer (score 0):

Let $S_1 = \sum_iD^t(i)\frac{1-C_iy_ih_t(x_i)}{2}$ and $S_2 = \sum_iD^t(i)\frac{1+C_iy_ih_t(x_i)}{2}$. Then, the right expresion is 
$$
f(\alpha) = e^{\alpha}S_1+e^{-\alpha}S_2.
$$
Therefore, 
$$
f'(\alpha) = e^{\alpha}S_1-e^{-\alpha}S_2.
$$
Making $f'(\alpha)=0$ one get $\alpha+\log S_1=-\alpha +\log S_2$ and $\alpha=(1/2)\log(S_2/S_1)$.